# How to use multiple themes in a SPA using angular 5

Tags: css, angular5

Need help in integrating multiple themes for a single page application.I have a landing page for my web app which is a html template and I have another theme used for the rest of my app.How do I avoid theme styles conflicts when i have a single index html ? Thing is the landing page theme should be my app root URL and also the login/signup pages which use the same styles as the landing page theme.The rest of the styles depends upon the other theme which i use for the rest of my app.So on doing this I am facing serious style conflicts.Any help would be really appreciated.Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

To have styles encapsulated for specific pages you should use their component's stylesheets instead of the global stylesheet.

If you need to import styles you should avoid doing so in the global stylesheet. You can import the external style for a specific component or if many components have the same number of stylesheets in common you could create a common stylesheet with all imports that you need.

That should allow for a flexibility with theming.

Comment: I tried adding imports in that particular component but I have a styles.css file which is a global style.So that file conflicts with the component css.That styles.css file is added to angular-cli.json styles array.

Comment: Normally it is the component's CSS that is prioritised over your global CSS. I would suggest avoiding any global CSS other than resets or styling components such as buttons, headers, and footers, but in your case, you might want to avoid it too since you have several themes in your application.

Comment: I tried adding the landing page theme in its own component css file but it has some background url in it which throws error on build

Comment: If you provide the assets make sure you put them inside the assets folder and then give the relative path to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this with grunt/gulp. Separate html and css from your app, both in an own repository. Have the base templates in one, and let grunt/gulp copy them over to the deploy directory. Then overwrite all files from the spcific template directory. Let's say you have this structure;

```
base-template/
  index.html
  other-template.html

my-template/
  other-template.html
```

Now when you copy them over, you'd have the `index.html` from the base template and the `other-template.html` file from your specific one, while the original template didn't change.

You can apply a similar strategy for css files, or any other asset for that matter.